# select autosuggest value(using jquery-ajax) by using uparrow and downarrow

Tags: jquery, ajax

i m using auto suggest box  [***fancy apple style suggestion box***](http://qpoit.com/marcofolio_demo/apple_search/) . everything is working fine, but i want that user can select any value that shown in suggestion box by up arrow or down arrow. how to implement code for this purpose.

right now user have to select given suggestion by using mouse.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JQuery Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete) plugin for this purpose. It has an easy implementation, and the end-user can use the arrow keys to select the desired results.